# Find owner of a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, files

I am looking for a way inside a bash script to return the owner of a file. I'm guessing that this is possible using "gawk" but I've honestly got no clue and there doesn't seem to be a comprehensible answer already posted online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `stat` for that.

In a GNU system:

- To get the username of the owner:

  ```
  stat -c '%U' file.txt
  ```
- To get the user ID (UID) of the owner:

  ```
  stat -c '%u' file.txt
  ```

Assuming the file is `file.txt`.

---

For FreeBSD and Mac OS X *(thanks to @cas)*:

- For username:

  ```
  stat -f '%Su' file.txt
  ```
- For UID:

  ```
  stat -f '%u' file.txt
  ```

Comment: WARNING: "stat" returns the string "UNKNOWN" for %U and %G if it is not defined in the system files. While "ls" will return the UID/GID if unknown. It is better to work with UID (%u) and GID (%g) numbers from "stat" if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l foo
```

Field #3 is owner, #4 is group.  So:

```
set -- $(ls -l foo) ; echo $3
```

But **stat** is better, when available.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `zsh` shell has its own `stat` builtin (and has had long before GNU and BSD added their own) in the `zsh/stat` module:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat +uid file
```

Will output the owner uid of the `file` after symlink resolution. If for symlinks, you want the owner of the symlink rather than the file is eventually resolves to, add the `-L` option (so `stat` does a `lstat()` instead of a `stat()`).

Add the `-s` option to translate that `uid` to a user name. If there are several usernames with the corresponding uid, it will report whichever is returned by `getpwuid()`. If there's no username for that uid, the uid will remain untranslated.

Long before GNU coreutils added a `stat` command, GNU `find` had the ability to to that with its `-printf` predicate:

```
find file -prune -printf '%U\n'
```

Replace `%U` with `%u` to translate the uid to one matching username. Add the `-H` option to follow symlinks and get the final target's owner.

POSIXly, you'd need to rely on `ls`:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -nd file | LC_ALL=C awk '{print $3; exit}'
```

Replace `-n` with `-l` to translate uid to one username (assuming the user name doesn't contain spaces nor tabs). Add the `-L` option to follow symlinks.

Comment: When invoking ls, it is beneficial to use `command ls` to suppress possible functions with the same name. To also handle possible aliases, `(unalias ls; ...)` could be used. Thus: `(unalias ls awk; LC_ALL=C command ls -nd file | LC_ALL=C command awk ...)`. On second thought, maybe using command and unalias for awk as well would be too much.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35931876/184064) lists more ways to prevent tampering, for example using `command -p ls` and `\unset -f unset` etc.